# Excel check if every occurrence in list is found

Tags: excel, list, lookup

I have a List of tests in an Excel file

```
List of Tests
   Test A
   Test B
   Test C
   Test D
```

In another file, I have a list of IDs and which tests are associated with an ID

```
ID  Test
25  Test A
25  Test B
25  Test B
25  Test C
25  Test D
26  Test A
26  Test B
26  Test C
26  Test D
27  Test A
27  Test A
27  Test B
27  Test C
28  Test A
28  Test B
28  Test C
28  Test D
```

I need to create a lookup which checks if the ID has EVERY test in the list and returns 1 if true, otherwise 0.

```
ID  Result
25  1
26  1
27  0
28  1
29  0
```

I've tried

`=SUMPRODUCT( -- ISNUMBER(SEARCH(List,IDs)))=COUNTA(List)` but this will return True if any match is found.

Comment: Can a given test be repeated for a given ID ? If No then it's just countif([id here]) = counta([list of tests])

Comment: Yes. I'll edit to show this, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the most elegant solution, but it works:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIFS(A$2:A$18,G2,B$2:B$18,K$2)>0,COUNTIFS(A$2:A$18,G2,B$2:B$18,K$3)>0,COUNTIFS(A$2:A$18,G2,B$2:B$18,K$4)>0,COUNTIFS(A$2:A$18,G2,B$2:B$18,K$5)>0),1,0)
```

And populate down

`Column A` contains the IDs (your second table)
`Column B` contains the tests (your second table)
`Column G` contains the list of unique IDs (your third table)
`Column H` contains the formula above
`Column K` contains the list of tests (your first table)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a data setup like this:

[image]

In cell G2 and copied down is this **array formula**:

```
=--AND(COUNTIFS(A:A,F2,B:B,$D$2:$D$5)>0)
```

Array formulas must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Explanation of formula:

Array formulas calculate arguments individually instead of collectively.  So in this case, it is doing a countifs to check if column A = [an ID] (F2) AND if column B is EACH of the list of tests (D2, D3, D4, and D5).  It checks for each of the D cells individually, and then returns an array (this is why they're referred to as array formulas) of the results.  If all of the tests exist, then you get {TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE} and the AND statement will return TRUE.  If any of the tests do not exist (for example, ID 27 will return {TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE} because Test D does not exist for ID 27), then the AND will see the false and return a FALSE result.  The -- (which can be read as minus negative, it's officially called a double unary and is used to convert non-numeric values to numbers) converts the TRUE/FALSE result from the AND statement to 1/0 respectively.

Comment: Well done, thank you! Would you mind explaining this formula a bit? I'm not familiar with array formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution (admittedly I'm not great at array formulas so...):

[image]

Entered in G25 using Ctrl+Shift+Enter and filled down